# Cannot save to Azure table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure-table-storage

I get `DataServiceRequestException` exception when I try to save an entity to azure table. It happens at this line `_myContext.SaveChangesWithRetries();` I've tried to google to see what the problem could be. But could not find any answer to it.

Anyone kow what the problem could be?

**Storage creator**

```
public CloudTableClient GetMusicClient() {
      //retrieve connection string from settings
      CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
          RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("StorageConnectionString"));

      //create table client
      CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

      //create table if doesn't exist
      string tableName = "music";
      tableClient.CreateTableIfNotExist(tableName);

      return tableClient;
}
```

**WebAPI**

```
public Music PostMusic(string genre, string artist, string random)
{
    CloudTableClient _myTableClient = _myTableRepo.GetMusicClient();
    TableServiceContext _myContext =  _myTableClient.GetDataServiceContext();

    Music music = new Music(genre, artist);
    music.Score = "10";
    music.Year = "2012";
    music.Random = random;
    try
    {
        _myContext.AddObject(random, music);
        _myContext.SaveChangesWithRetries();
    }
    catch (StorageClientException e)
    { }
    catch (DataServiceRequestException e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    }

    return music;

}
```

**stacktrace**

```
An error occurred while processing this request.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait()
   at MyWebAPI.Controllers.ValuesController.PostMusic(String genre, String artist, String random) in C:\MyWebAPI\MyWebAPI\Controllers\ValuesController.cs:line 61
```

**Music.cs**

```
public class Music : TableServiceEntity
    {
        public Music(string genre, string artist)
        {
            this.PartitionKey = genre;
            this.RowKey = artist;
        }
        public Music() {}
        public string Score { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public string Random { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code for Music? Is there a partition key and a row key? What are the other fields?

Comment: In general, it helps to use Fiddler to debug things like this. You may get better info about the exact error.

Comment: @smarx Yes, I have both partition key and row key. I added the code for the Music to my question now. What is Fiddler, is it included in VS2010?

Comment: Here's Fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, it looks like your first argument to AddObject is wrong? It should be "music," the name of your table, but if the parameter name is to be believed, it looks like you're passing in a random string.